# How to count average "kill score" of mobile app users with flurry

Tags: android, ios, mobile, flurry

Let's say I'm developing a mobile game where you have to kill zombies. I'd like to use Flurry Analytics to track the number of zombies that the average user kills. I ask because I want to build an in app purchase to allow users to buy more bullets, but first I need to know how many bullets to give for free, and this depends on how many zombies the average user kills (and I already know that it takes 5 bullets per zombie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use custom events for knowing how many Zombies the user kills.

Are you aware of events on Flurry ? Please see the below link for more info-

http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/Events

You can setup an event 'Zombie Killed'

You can basically make a call to logEvent whenever the user kills a Zombie.

Once you have this event setup, Flurry will report the below metrics-

1. Avg number of events
2. Avg events per session
3. Avg events per user

Does this help ? If you need more info, please reach out to us on support@flurry.com